# Solving systems of Differential equations of $\vec{\phi} = A e^{\vec{\phi}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve following systems of differential equation

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\begin{pmatrix}
\phi_1(t) \\
\phi_2(t)
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
e^{\phi_1(t)} \\
e^{\phi_2(t)}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where $a,b,c,d$ are constant.

Is there any way to solve this? Here I have difficulty of handling $e^{\phi_{1}(t)}$ and $e^{\phi_2{(t)}}$

Comment: Have you tried looking to, basically, ANY ODE book ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas, of course for the usual one, $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\vec{\phi} = A \vec{\phi}$ as covered in usual ODE textbook, I can solve this, but I am trying to find above case in some literature but at this moment no ODE textbook covers this kinds of problem